# Product Label Report Setup (no report found in the Report name dropdown)

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I've been trying to print labels in dynamics AX 2012 r2.
I'm following this link:

http://dynamicsaxtipoftheday.com/2014/04/30/generate-product-bar-code-labels-through-retail

Somehow when I get to the Product label report setup form, there is no reports in the report name dropdown.

See screencast: http://screencast.com/t/KVHAIKZ4cT

I have already deployed the RetailLabel report, (A4Landscape3X5_ItemReport and A4Portrait3X5_ShelfReport)

I have also installed the Retail Components.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get the report to show in the dropdown?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup queries the system table `UtilElements` with the conditions `name == 'RetailLabel*'` and `recordType == UtilElementType::OutputTool`. Make sure the `UtilElements` table contains records for these conditions. The elements are output menu items called `RetailLabelA4Landscape3x5_Item` and `RetailLabelA4Protrait3x5_Shelf`. Also make sure that configuration key `RetailHeadquarters` is activated. I tested the lookup successfully on a AX 2012 R2 CU7 system.

[image: Lookup Retail Label Report]

Comment: Thank you for you responding. RetailHeadquarters config key is activated and RetailLabelA4Landscape3x5_Item and RetailLabelA4Protrait3x5_Shelf are found in the utilElements table but still it doesn't show in the dropdown. In the utilElements table, the Source column is null for the two reports. Is there something else that we're missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by modifying the query used in populating the dropdown list.